# Discord.py: I can't increase the value of an Int inside my config.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I can't increase the value of the Int pinggoals which is inside my config.py.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import *
import asyncio

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '*ping' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send(' Pong! \r Bot / ' + str(ponggoals) + ' : 0 \\ Users')
        pinggoals += 1
```

my config.py is just `pinggoals = 1`

Comment: since `pinggoals` is immutable, when you update it in the function you are creating a local copy. you will want to either add `global pinggoals` in the start of the function, or have `pinggoals` as a mutable, like part of a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to declare the variable outside of the `if` statement. Something like this should work:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from config import *
import asyncio


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    pinggoals = 0  # You can't increase a non-number, change this to whatever you want
    if '*ping' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send(' Pong! \r Bot / ' + str(ponggoals) + ' : 0 \\ Users')
        pinggoals += 1
```

The reason I don't think having `global pinggoals` will work, is because pinggoals is not set to an integer, and you can't add one to nothing.

Comment: The `piggoals` variable will reset everytime the event is called, so it will always be 0, pretty sure he doesn't want that

Answer (score 0):

What **Nullman** suggested in the comments:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global pinggoals
    if '*ping' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send(' Pong! \r Bot / ' + str(ponggoals) + ' : 0 \\ Users')
        pinggoals += 1
```